# Firemonkey working with Alt + Char

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, shortcut, alt-key

My goal is to hook the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and while it is down, process the next char pressed as a shortcut key, the way the <kbd>Ctl</kbd> key works in a `TMenuItem`.

I tried the `FormKeyUp` event but it never returns `ssAlt` in the `Shift` parameter.

How can I accomplish this? Is there any Windows message that I can hook to detect that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is down?

Comment: Look at `GetKeyState()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()` in the Win32 API

Comment: @Remy. I wonder why is it that the `FormKeyUp` event does not return the proper values in case of the `Alt`key. Do you have any clue?